# What's the difference between initializing a vector in Class Header or Class constructor body?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, segmentation-fault, initialization

I encountered a strange behavior in my C++ program that I don't understand and I don't know how to search for more information. So I ask for advice here hoping someone might know.

I have a class `Interface` that has a 2 dimensional vector that I initialize in the header :

```cpp
class Interface {
public:
// code...
  const unsigned short int SIZE_X_ = 64;
  const unsigned short int SIZE_Y_ = 32;
  std::vector<std::vector<bool>> screen_memory_ =
          std::vector<std::vector<bool>>(SIZE_X_, std::vector<bool>(SIZE_Y_, false));

// code...
};
```

Here I expect that I have a `SIZE_X_` x `SIZE_Y_` vector filled with false booleans.

Later in my program I loop at a fixed rate like so :

```cpp
void Emulator::loop() {

  const milliseconds intervalPeriodMillis{static_cast<int>((1. / FREQ) * 1000)};

  //Initialize the chrono timepoint & duration objects we'll be //using over & over inside our sleep loop
  system_clock::time_point currentStartTime{system_clock::now()};
  system_clock::time_point nextStartTime{currentStartTime};

  while (!stop) {
    currentStartTime = system_clock::now();
    nextStartTime = currentStartTime + intervalPeriodMillis;

    // ---- Stuff happens here ----
    registers_->trigger_timers();
    interface_->toogle_buzzer();
    interface_->poll_events();
    interface_->get_keys();
    romParser_->step();
    romParser_->decode();
    // ---- ------------------ ----

    stop = stop || interface_->requests_close();
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(nextStartTime);
  }
}
```

But then during the execution I get a segmentation fault

> [1]    7585 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./CHIP8 coin.ch8

I checked with the debugger and some part of the `screen_memory_` cannot be accessed anymore. And it seems to happen at random time.

But when I put the initialization of the vector in the constructor body like so :

```cpp
Interface::Interface(const std::shared_ptr<reg::RegisterManager> & registers, bool hidden)
    : registers_(registers) {

  // code ...

  screen_memory_ =
          std::vector<std::vector<bool>>(SIZE_X_, std::vector<bool>(SIZE_Y_, false));

  // code ...
}
```

The segmentation fault doesn't happen anymore. So the solution is just to initialize the vector in the constructor body.

But why ? what is happening there ?
I don't understand what I did wrong, I'm sure someone knows.

Thanks for your help !

---

**[Edit] I found the source of the bug (Or at least what to change so it doesnt give me a segfault anymore).**

In my class `Interface` I use the SDL and SDL_audio libraries to create the display and the buzzer sound. Have a special look where I set the callback `want_.callback`, the callback `Interface::forward_audio_callback` and `Interface::audio_callback`. Here's the code :

```cpp
// (c) 2021 Maxandre Ogeret
// Licensed under MIT License

#include "Interface.h"

Interface::Interface(const std::shared_ptr<reg::RegisterManager> & registers, bool hidden)
    : registers_(registers) {

  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_AUDIO != 0) || SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Unable to initialize rendering engine.");
  }

  want_.freq = SAMPLE_RATE;
  want_.format = AUDIO_S16SYS;
  want_.channels = 1;
  want_.samples = 2048;
  want_.callback = Interface::forward_audio_callback;
  want_.userdata = &sound_userdata_;

  if (SDL_OpenAudio(&want_, &have_) != 0) {
    SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_AUDIO, "Failed to open audio: %s", SDL_GetError());
  }
  if (want_.format != have_.format) {
    SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_AUDIO, "Failed to get the desired AudioSpec");
  }

  window = SDL_CreateWindow("CHIP8", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                            SIZE_X_ * SIZE_MULTIPLIER_, SIZE_Y_ * SIZE_MULTIPLIER_,
                            hidden ? SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN : 0);

  renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE);
  bpp_ = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window)->format->BytesPerPixel;
  SDL_Delay(1000);

//  screen_memory_ = std::vector<std::vector<bool>>(SIZE_X_, std::vector<bool>(SIZE_Y_, false));
}

Interface::~Interface() {
  SDL_CloseAudio();
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
}

// code ...

void Interface::audio_callback(void * user_data, Uint8 * raw_buffer, int bytes) {
  audio_buffer_ = reinterpret_cast<Sint16 *>(raw_buffer);
  sample_length_ = bytes / 2;
  int & sample_nr(*(int *) user_data);

  for (int i = 0; i < sample_length_; i++, sample_nr++) {
    double time = (double) sample_nr / (double) SAMPLE_RATE;
    audio_buffer_[i] = static_cast<Sint16>(
            AMPLITUDE * (2 * (2 * floor(220.0f * time) - floor(2 * 220.0f * time)) + 1));
  }
}

void Interface::forward_audio_callback(void * user_data, Uint8 * raw_buffer, int bytes) {
  static_cast<Interface *>(user_data)->audio_callback(user_data, raw_buffer, bytes);
}
}
```

In the function `Interface::audio_callback`, replacing the class variable assignation :

```cpp
sample_length_ = bytes / 2;
```

By an int creation and assignation :

```cpp
int sample_length = bytes / 2;
```

which gives :

```cpp
void Interface::audio_callback(void * user_data, Uint8 * raw_buffer, int bytes) {
  audio_buffer_ = reinterpret_cast<Sint16 *>(raw_buffer);
  int sample_length = bytes / 2;
  int &sample_nr(*(int*)user_data);

  for(int i = 0; i < sample_length; i++, sample_nr++)
  {
    double time = (double)sample_nr / (double)SAMPLE_RATE;
    audio_buffer_[i] = (Sint16)(AMPLITUDE * sin(2.0f * M_PI * 441.0f * time)); // render 441 HZ sine wave
  }

}
```

The class variable `sample_length_` is defined and initialized as private in the header like so :

```cpp
int sample_length_ = 0;
```

So I had an idea and I created the variable sample_length_ as public and it works ! So the problem was definitely a scope problem of the class variable `sample_length_`. But it doesn't explain why the segfault disappeared when I moved the init of some other variable in the class constructor... Did I hit some undefined behavior with my callback ?

Thanks for reading me !

Comment: In the first example, well both actually, Where are `SIZE_X_` and `SIZE_Y_` declared/defined?

Comment: In the header of my class, in the class declaration.
Edited the post to include them

Comment: I think that it has something to do with the linker.

Comment: Try reducing it to minimal complete example and post that here.

Comment: I will try thanks. I tried running my program with valgrind and it doesnt crashg when I do so. What could it mean ? It's making me even more confused

Comment: Found the problem and updated my post. I'd still like some insight though.